# Is ipad version required to publish on apple store?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I am new to iOS development and the response to this question may seem obvious for some experimented developers. If I create an application that targets iPhone, do I really need to include views also for iPad before submitting the applicatio  to Apple Store?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, you can target only the iPhone if you want.  Or you can target specifically the iPad.  Finally you can create a Universal app that targets both.

It's your choice.  You define what you're targeting in your project.

Answer (score 5):

AFAIK You need to submit the screenshots for `iPad` as well even you are submitting app for the `iPhone`. I am talking about the itunesconnect while you are submitting. I have experienced this myself when submitted app for `iPhone` only and was mandatory to add `iPad` screenshots.

Specifically to Targets or Views in your xcode. **NO** you don't need to add any extra view, only the views for your target. In case of keeping app universal you could add views for `iPhone` and `iPad`.

For taking different screenshots, you don't need to add different views but instead you can use simulator to take all variants of screenshots.

Comment: What means screenshoots for iPad? I mean, if I need to provide screenshots I also need to create views for iPad or I can just resize the iPhone version's screenshoots?

Comment: screenshots are the picture which appears in the appstore as preview for your app

Comment: No you don't need to add views for screenshots, you can take the screenshots using Simulator

Comment: I think this answer is not very clear. It should say: you need to submit iPad screenshots only if your app is built to be universal. If you plan to release an iPhone only app, then you do not need to supply iPad screenshots (@RichardBrown is a lot clearer on that).

Comment: I think I made it clear by writing mandatory even in case of submitting for iPhone Application, I had target set for iPhone and I was required to submit the iPad screenshots in order to proceed in application submission.

Answer (score 4):

I recently tried to submit a app to iTunes with screenshots for iPad and the binary was only for iPhone.

This is what they informed me.

**Your binary doesn’t support iPad. The screenshots or app video preview
for iPad won’t be shown on the App Store**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you target your app to be Universal you will need both, and if you only select a device, iphone example you don't need for ipad.

Comment: I can publish an app that specifically targets only iPhone? I ask this because I don't know how I understood that if you want to publish an app to the app store, you need versions for both iPhone and iPad if you want the app to be accepted and published by Apple.

Comment: Yes. If you said the your app only supports iPhone there is no problem, you can still download from appstore using a iPad but you will see that the app is only for iPhone/iPod. Apple will not reject your app for that reason. I have a app that is only for iPhone/iPod but some people have download it from iPad.

Answer (score 1):

For universal you need to submit both otherwise the one you set target will be enough